# How do I determine the sign of $\sin\theta$ in this question.

Tags: trigonometry

> $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two different values of $\theta$ lying between $0$ and $2\pi$ which satisfy the equation $\begin{equation}6\cos\theta + 8\sin\theta = 9\end{equation}$. Find $\sin(\alpha+\beta).$

I solved and got $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{-28}{100}$.
So $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \pm\frac{24}{25}$.
I think the sign of $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ could be either of '+' and '-', however my book says it must be '+'. How do I determine the sign?

Comment: this means the angle is between $0$ and $\pi$

Comment: @Semsem Which angle?

Comment: $0\le \alpha+\beta \le \pi$ . .

Comment: @Semsem Why so?

Comment: I try to guess why your book put this condition

Comment: How did you solve for $\cos(\alpha + \beta)$? I bet there's a pretty good chance you could modify the derivation to solve for $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$ directly, without going through $\cos$ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is correct. We don't need to find either $\alpha$ or $\beta$, i.e. to solve the given linear equation in $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, which could be transformed into a quadratic equation in $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$.

[EDIT. Since you've commented that your course was a beginner's one, I edited this answer to add the derivation of all trigonomatric identities I used, from the addition and subtraction formulas.]

Equating the equations satisfied by $\alpha$ and $\beta$

\begin{eqnarray*}
6\cos \alpha +8\sin \alpha  &=&9\tag{1} \\
6\cos \beta +8\sin \beta  &=&9,\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

and then simplyfying and rearranging, we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
3\left( \cos \alpha -\cos \beta \right)  &=&4\left( \sin \beta -\sin \alpha
\right)  .\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray*}

Applying the [sum-to-product identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \alpha -\cos \beta  &=&-2\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\sin \frac{\alpha
-\beta }{2} \tag{4}\\
\sin \beta -\sin \alpha  &=&-2\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha
+\beta }{2},\tag{5}
\end{eqnarray*}

assuming$^1$ that  $\sin \frac{\alpha-\beta }{2}\ne 0 $ we have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
-3\times 2\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}
&=&-4\times 2\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\tag{6} \\
3\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2} &=&4\cos \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\tag{7} \\
\tan \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2} &=&\frac{4}{3}.\tag{8}
\end{eqnarray*}

Finally expressing $\sin \left( \alpha +\beta \right) $ in terms of $\tan 
\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}$, using the [double-angle identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) we find

\begin{equation*}
\sin \left( \alpha +\beta \right) =\frac{2\tan \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}{
1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}=\frac{2\left( \frac{4}{3}\right) }{
1+\left( \frac{4}{3}\right) ^{2}}=\frac{24}{25},\tag{9}
\end{equation*}

which agrees with the $\cos \left( \alpha +\beta \right) $ value you found:

\begin{equation*}
\cos \left( \alpha +\beta \right) =\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}
}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}=\frac{1-\left( \frac{4}{3}\right) ^{2}
}{1+\left( \frac{4}{3}\right) ^{2}}=-\frac{7}{25}.\tag{10}
\end{equation*}

EDIT. **Justification** of:

- Identity $(4)$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  \cos \left( a\pm b\right)  &=&\cos a\cos b\mp \sin a\sin b \\
  &&\text{If }\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c}
  a+b=\alpha  \\ 
  a-b=\beta ,
  \end{array}
  \right. \text{ then }\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c}
  a=\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2} \\ 
  b=\frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}
  \end{array}
  \right. \text{ and} \\
  \cos \alpha  &=&\cos \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}
  -\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2} \\
  \cos \beta  &=&\cos \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}
  +\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2} \\
  \cos \alpha -\cos \beta  &=&-2\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\sin \frac{\alpha
  -\beta }{2}.
  \end{eqnarray*}
- Identity $(5)$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  \sin \left( a\pm b\right)  &=&\sin a\cos b\pm \sin b\cos a \\
  &&\text{If }\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c}
  a+b=\alpha  \\ 
  a-b=\beta ,
  \end{array}
  \right. \text{ then }\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c}
  a=\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2} \\ 
  b=\frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}
  \end{array}
  \right. \text{ and} \\
  \sin \alpha  &=&\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}
  +\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2} \\
  \sin \beta  &=&\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}
  -\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2} \\
  \sin \beta -\sin \alpha  &=&-2\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\cos \frac{\alpha
  +\beta }{2}.
  \end{eqnarray*}
- identities $(9)$ and $(10)$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  \sin \left( \alpha +\beta \right)  &=&2\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\cos 
  \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}=\frac{2\sin \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\cos \frac{
  \alpha +\beta }{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}+\sin ^{2}\frac{\alpha
  +\beta }{2}} \\
  &=&\frac{2\tan \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}
  \\
  && \\
  \cos \left( \alpha +\beta \right)  &=&\cos ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}-\sin
  ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}=\frac{\cos ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}-\sin
  ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}+\sin ^{2}
  \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}} \\
  &=&\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\alpha +\beta 
  }{2}}
  \end{eqnarray*}

--

$^1$ The assumption $\sin \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}\neq 0$ is valid because if $
0\neq \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2}=\pi $, then without loss of generality we might
assume that $0=\beta <\alpha =2\pi $, but we would get a contradition:

\begin{eqnarray*}
6\cos \left( 2\pi \right) +8\sin \left( 2\pi \right)  &\neq &9 \\
6\cos \left( 0\right) +8\sin \left( 0\right)  &\neq &9.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Prosthaphaeresis Formulas
(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) are fine. But, we need to explain why $$\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\ne0$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee You are right!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Please see my edit.

Comment: I was thinking in that line. What's more interesting is the Right Hand Side is $(9)$ is immaterial here. But, $$(6\cos\theta+8\sin\theta)^2\le(6^2+8^2)(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)\le100\iff-10\le 6\cos\theta+8\sin\theta\le10$$ Then what if the RHS $>10$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You won't face such confusion if you adapt the following method:

Use [Weierstrass substitution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html)  to form a Quadratic Equation  in $\tan \frac x2$

Then use Trigonometric Addition Formulas to find $\displaystyle\tan\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\right)$

Finally use [this](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/proving-trigonometric-identities-prove-sin2a-2tana-233205)

Comment: While I was solving the question, I got $\cos\alpha + \cos\beta = 27/25$ and $\cos\alpha\cdot\cos\beta = 17/100$. That would imply that both $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\beta$ are positive.

Comment: @shauryagupta, how have you solved ?

Comment: My course is a beginner's course, so I don't think that book writer would have gone about doing the question the way you are.

Comment: Squaring both sides of $6\cos\theta - 9 = -8\sin\theta$ and then replacing $sin^2\theta$ by $1-\cos^2\theta$ and using vieta's formula.

Comment: @shauryagupta, on squaring, you have immediately introduced an extraneous root, right?

Comment: Can you please tell me why?

Comment: @shauryagupta, one solution is the root of $$6\cos\theta-9=8\sin\theta$$ right? Are you allowed to use inverse trig functions?

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to use inverse trig functions.

Comment: I understand the extraneous root thing...So how should have I solved the question?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin \theta=\frac{2\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}$$
$$\cos \theta=\frac{1-\tan^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}$$
Substitute the above two equations in the main equation and let $\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = x$. Now you get a quadratic equation $x$ from where you can find $x=\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$.
Then find $\sin (\alpha+\beta)$ from here.